# Setting locale to app widget

Tags: android, localization, android-appwidget

Our application enforces a certain locale to it independent of device settings. This is a temporary decision until the strings are translated properly.

```
    Configuration config = sContext.getResources().getConfiguration();
    if (!sDefaultLocale.equals(config.locale)) {
            Locale.setDefault(sDefaultLocale);
            config.locale = sDefaultLocale;
            sContext.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    sContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    }
```

Unfortunately, forcing locale doesn't work with app widget, the widget still uses locale of device. I am looking for a way to make the app widget assume the same locale.

Comment: where above mentioned code is called ? it will be good if you share the location from where you are setting the locale and what are you doing after this code ?  This will help in answering your code more appropriate.

Comment: any  luck  with the  solution?

Comment: have you found a solution for it?!

Answer (score 2):

After changing the locale you need to update the app widgets. And the important part is that when creating new RemoteViews, you need to set all your strings **programmatically**, using remoteViews.setTextViewText(..).

if app widget string resources are defined in XML (android:text="@string/...") - they will not be changed after setting the new locale.